# Laravel: Getting attribute/column value in model constructor

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get the attribute/column of the model in constructor to initialise a class in the Model based on that value. But I can't get the part getting the value working

I have something like this in my code. But it keeps giving me null:

```
public $job;

public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->job = $this->__get('name');
}
```

Whenever I try it on Tinker, it works perfectly fine:

```
$user = User::first();
$user->__get('name')
```

Comment: The proper way is just `$user->name`, the `__get()` is the magic method access which you don't interfaace with directly.

Comment: I am not sure but I think the reason is: when you use $user->__get('name'), $user is created as a good instance and you can call function extended from its parent. But in the __construct(), it is not ready for $this to __get('name'). Maybe you can use $this->job = $attributes['name']; in your case.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Yes I will definitely not use the magic method `__get` outside model. This is something to prove `__get` should work in the controller